# Preserve Client IP address in Azure API Management with Application Gateway scenario

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have **Azure Application Gateway** and **API Management** configured in this setup
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway - Application Gateway is the public endpoint and only defined routes are passed through to API Management.

I want to use the `ip-filter` policy to restrict calls to certain IP addresses. However when calls are coming through Application Gateway, the original client IP address is lost or obfuscated to IP `0.0.0.0`.

Is there a way to keep the original client IP address and pass it through from Application Gateway to API Management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find this article useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works#modifications-to-the-request

> An application gateway inserts four additional headers to all requests
>   before it forwards the requests to the backend. These headers are
>   x-forwarded-for, x-forwarded-proto, x-forwarded-port, and
>   x-original-host. The format for x-forwarded-for header is a
>   comma-separated list of IP:port.

Comment: You are right. I already checked HTTP header x-forwarded-for - it would allow to implement some own block logic as a fall back with this policy expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#CheckHTTPHeader.

Comment: I checked and for me this solution is not working as the Request-X-Forwarded-For HTTP header contains a varying port information which makes it impossible to filter for a defined set of IP addresses. The other headers suggested in this solution do not contain the required information to filter on.

Comment: OK, if I reduce the header value before doing the check, it works: <set-header name="X-Forwarded-For" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
            string headerValue = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-forwarded-for","");
            string[] tokens = headerValue.Split(':');
            if(tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                headerValue = tokens[0];
            }
            return headerValue;
            }</value>
        </set-header> <check-header name="X-Forwarded-For"...